# Java exception for using String.Split() method: Dangling meta character

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse a URL string (which I am receiving via HTML Get method) and extract the embedded options. I'm wondering why it drops an exception on `s=s.split("?")[0];`

`Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 0`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s= "run.html?yse=yse1&tracefile=capacity.1Mbps_c50.txt&fd=100&rd=100&down=1&up=1&per=0.00001";
    s=s.split("?")[0];  //drops error
    String ss[]=s.split("&");
//this is a class I have that receives the array of splitted options.
    JavaRunEmulator j = new JavaRunEmulator(ss);
    System.out.println(j.getOutput());
}
```

Comment: Yes...I'm now using "\\?", and it works! Interesting; I learned about this fact for "?"!

Comment: so, you can check your question as resolved

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the `split()` method takes a **regular expression** as an input.

> ```
> public String[] split(String regex)
> ```
>
> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

The character `?` is used to identify certain [patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) in regex, including some of the following

> **Greedy quantifiers**
> X? :   X, once or not at all
>
> **Reluctant quantifiers**
> X?? : X, once or not at all
> X*? : X, zero or more times
> X+? : X, one or more times
> X{n}? : X, exactly n times
> X{n,}? : X, at least n times
> X{n,m}?   : X, at least n but not more than m times
>
> **Possessive quantifiers**
> X?+ : X, once or not at all

If you escape the string like this

```
s=s.split("\\?")[0];
```

the `?` won't be treated like it is being used in a pattern and is instead a raw string.